Detecting elapsed time between entries with DAX
I have 3 columns
USER_ID, DATE, AND TIME
I am attempting to create a calculated column the will
A) Find entries in the table with the same user id, date and an earlier time
B) calculate the difference between those values
C) if there is no earlier entry it will set elapsed time as 0
D) convert the result into a float
Elapsed Time (Hours-Column) = 
VAR CurrentTransactionTime = PROD[TIME]
VAR PreviousTransactionTime =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(PROD[TIME]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(PROD),
            PROD[USER_ID] = EARLIER(PROD[USER_ID]) &&
            PROD[DATE] = EARLIER(PROD[DATE]) &&
            PROD[TIME] < CurrentTransactionTime
        )
    )
VAR ElapsedTimeInSeconds = DATEDIFF(PreviousTransactionTime, CurrentTransactionTime, SECOND)
VAR ElapsedTimeInHours = DIVIDE(ElapsedTimeInSeconds, 3600, 0)
RETURN
IF(
    ISBLANK(PreviousTransactionTime) || ISBLANK(CurrentTransactionTime),
    0,
    ROUND(ElapsedTimeInHours, 2)
)

my current formula works however if two events have the same transaction time the filter in the previoustransaction time function will find the record with the previous time and calculate datediff from there instead of the entry with the same timestamp.
the filter in my formula isn't behaving as intended. it is grabbing an earlier timestamp and not the similar timestamp and duplicating the elapsed time from the original entry instead of setting elapsed time at 0
What I want it to do
What it does

Can you please provide a table of sample data and expected output, so we can replicate this question?

I included a couple pictures with sample data

The only way I could get this to work was by adding an index column to differentiate between the two duplicate rows. So I changed the sort order of the table and added an index column in Power Query. Here are those steps:

Sort by User_ID Ascending, Date Ascending, then Time Ascending.
Add Index Column

Code:
let
    //Original query steps
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45W8vJ3VdJRMtU3MtI3MjAyAbINrQwMlGJ1opWCQ1zDcEoGeTp745LDZqYxQSmsJhrjcwpOM40wXGKM6shYAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"USER ID" = _t, DATE = _t, TIME = _t]),
    #"Changed Type"  = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"USER ID", type text}, {"DATE", type date}, {"TIME", type time}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"USER ID", "USER_ID"}}),
    
    //Add these steps to the query
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Renamed Columns",{{"USER_ID", Order.Ascending}, {"DATE", Order.Ascending}, {"TIME", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type)
in
    #"Added Index"

Then once we have that Index column we can use it to filter the table by all rows less than our current index.
Updated Calculated Column:
Elapsed Time (Hours-Column) Updated = 

VAR thisUser = [USER_ID]
VAR thisDate = [DATE]
VAR CurrentTransactionTime = [TIME]
VAR thisIndex = [Index]


VAR PreviousTransactionTime =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(PROD[TIME]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(PROD),
            PROD[USER_ID] = thisUser &&
            PROD[DATE] = thisDate &&
            PROD[Index] < thisIndex
        )
    )   

VAR ElapsedTimeInSeconds = DATEDIFF(PreviousTransactionTime, CurrentTransactionTime, SECOND)
VAR ElapsedTimeInHours = DIVIDE(ElapsedTimeInSeconds, 3600, 0)
RETURN
IF(
    ISBLANK(PreviousTransactionTime) || ISBLANK(CurrentTransactionTime),
    0,
    ROUND(ElapsedTimeInHours, 2)
)

Output:



USER_ID
DATE
TIME
Index
Elapsed Time (Hours-Column)
Elapsed Time (Hours-Column) Updated




JOE
05/22/2024
1:00
0
0
0


JOE
05/22/2024
1:30
1
0.5
0.5


JOE
05/22/2024
1:30
2
0.5
0


JOE
05/22/2024
2:00
3
0.5
0.5


JOE
05/23/2024
1:00
4
0
0


RICK
05/22/2024
1:00
5
0
0


RICK
05/22/2024
1:30
6
0.5
0.5


STEVE
05/22/2024
1:00
7
0
0


STEVE
05/22/2024
1:30
8
0.5
0.5




I am having trouble updating the power query because there are multiple applied steps.  is there a way to roll up the data type changes and renamed columns into a single function?

You don't need to worry about merging them into one step. You can take the name of your last step (ex: #"Renamed Columns") and replace the "PreviousSteps" in the #"Sorted Rows" step:
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Renamed Columns",{{"USER_ID", Order.Ascending}, {"DATE", Order.Ascending}, {"TIME", Order.Ascending}}),

I updated my answer with both the original query and the updated steps.
